# Why does HIVE depend on a Server URL and HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I've noticed that HIVE has alot of dependencies , including a server url as well as HBASE, from scanning over the bigtop integration tests.

See: https://github.com/cloudera/bigtop/blob/master/test/src/smokes/hive/src/test/groovy/com/cloudera/itest/hivesmoke/TestJdbcDriver.java

In any case, I wonder -- originally it seemed that Hive was essentially a way to translate SQL declarations into MapReduce jobs.

What is the role of hbase and the "hive server" in the Hive world of operations ?  Can Hive stand on its own as a SQL -> MapReduce client, or are these hard , global requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the github code, we can see that is a smoke-test module by cloudera which needs to use JDBC to 'connect' Hive. But actually we can surely use hive without the 'server' or 'HBase'.

1) for the server URL, it is URL to connect to a thrift server from remote Java API. The server here is like a facade to the Hive world (you could refer to [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html) or the pic below). The server needs to be started by [`hive --service hiveserver &`](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9781449326944/16dot-hive-thrift-service/_starting_the_thrift_server_html) . You could skip the server and directly use Hive CLI (embedded mode), as mentioned [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveclient.html).

```
   +-----------+      +-------------+     +--------------+
   |           |      |             |     |              |
   |java client+----->|hive server  +----->metastore srv |
   |           |      |             |     |              |
   +-----------+      +-------------+     +------+-------+
                                                 |
                                                 v
                                           +--------------+
                                           |              |
                                           |    Database  |
                                           |              |
                                           +--------------+
```

2) as for HBase, you could care nothing about it if you are not gonna use HBase. Hive is a data warehouse tool, and it can deal with data located on HDFS, HBase and so on. To access HDFS is straightforward, but to access HBase is kinda complicated by using ["Hive-HBase-Integration"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration).